# Fetch and divide data in Data Types in C from MySQL

Tags: mysql, c

I come today before you to ask this question:

How would I go about parsing specific data for a login system in C without having to get each individual row, store it, brake it in parts, check for the parts I need and then release the memory.

This is what I have so far, and it might be primitive but bear with me.

```
MYSQL_ROW row;

char *ID;
char *username;
char *password;
char *power;
char *cash;


while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
    { 
        ID = strtok(row[i], " ");
        username = strtok(NULL, " ");
        username = strtok(NULL, " ");
        power = strtok(NULL, " ");
        cash = strtok(NULL, " "); 
    }  
}
```

Is there a simpler, less primitive way of checking through a database, say **testdb** having the table **users** with 5 fields and check just for the username and password. Say, it has the ID 5 and the username John. Now, I retain that 5 and I check for the password at ID five and if that is correct fetch the rest. So if like, say cash, power and something else is an integer, fetch an integer and not a string.

I am new to MySQL so I am not entirely sure how to adapt that to C.

Comment: Im am not a c dev, but c#. just ask something, is your while loop working? No more query scripts on it, how you construct your query?

Comment: I am sure that the while loop is working, but I am asking if there is a simple way to retrieving information. For example, how can I code it to check through specific fields.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a row which has specific `username` and `password` without checking all the records in table? Probably you should modify the SQL query. Can you show us the SQL query which was executed in order to produce `result`?

Comment: Yes. How would I go about doing that? Query:  'MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(connection);'   'int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);' 'mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM users")'